# Unable to get response from a web service using KSoap

Tags: android

I am using Ksoap2 api for integrating the web services. The web services that require no input from user, are working fine.

But in case of input it is giving SoapFault Exception.

I am sharing the code here and details.

I'm given a envelop string for this method:

Article:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:def="http://DefaultNamespace">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<def:article soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<articleID xsi:type="xsd:double">$ARTICLEID</articleID>
</def:article>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code:

```
private String getNewsDetails() {

        String URL = "http://heinrich.house.gov/common/site/mobile.cfc?WSDL";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://DefaultNamespace/";

        String METHOD_NAME = "article";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://DefaultNamespace/article";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("articleID", "590");   //590 or 592 etc... for test-case

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
//      envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            Log.e("Response", "getNewsDetails..." + resultsRequestSOAP);
            return resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG","IOException...."+e);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage(e.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e("TAG","XmlPullParserException...."+e);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage(e.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the response:

```
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.view/com.demo.view.Demo}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at com.demo.view.Demo.getNewsDetails(Demo.java:141)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at com.demo.view.Demo.onCreate(Demo.java:36)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
04-20 18:32:24.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(940):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete "**`?WSDL`**" part from URL String.

Comment: It worked after replacing the latest version of ksoap api